# Share transaction between ado.net and entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, ado.net

I have an application where we are using transaction scope similar to the one given below. Inside this transaction scope, there will be select query running in EF and there is a fetch method called in ADO.Net. In this process, I am getting a connection timeout exception. However if i remove the transaction scope, it works fine.

Is there a way for us to fix the issue or anyone can explain the behavior.

```
 using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions
            {
                IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
            }))
            {
//call to EF
// call to ADO.Net
            }
```

Comment: Entity Framework uses ADO.NET transactios. If it didn't you wouldn't get an exception. Post the offending code. For some reason either you end up opening two connections, or the code deadlocks with another operation

Comment: Can you post your ADO method? Have you tried setting your `cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;` in ADO? Have you ran a Profiler session to see if you can interrogate the queries being executed? Have you tried setting your `Timeout` on your `TransactionOptions`?

Comment: I have a few findings, 1) enterprise library database objects were used, 2) I am trying to profile and check how many new connections are started & how many transactions are in place. I will test this and post my findings here